# How can I update sentencepiece package to its latest version using conda?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, sentencepiece

I have installed conda on linux ubuntu 16. When I install or update a package named [sentencepiece](https://github.com/google/sentencepiece) it install the version 0.1.85 (which I guess is from 2 months ago according to anaconda website). However the latest version is 0.1.91.

I can't install the latest version so that I can use it in python because I guess it refers to the conda packages. I tried to follow an instruction in the package home on github and installed the latest version using a package manager named vcpkg. However, I don't think it has any effect on python or conda, as a sample program didn't compile and the conda still list it as 0.1.85

please guide me what can I do

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip` instead of `conda`

First step - `conda activate <your_env>`
Next step - `pip install sentencepiece`

Then last step - check the version using `pip freeze | grep "sentence*"`

Output should be `sentencepiece==0.1.91`

Comment: thanks, however I used `pip install sentencepiece==0.1.91` because without the version it says it's `Requirement already satisfied: sentencepiece in /home/pouramini/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages (0.1.85)`

Comment: Even better way is - uninstall and re-install the package